# PowerShell script to get data from Solr and Edit in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore-client, solr, powershell-extensions, powershell

Is there a way that i can **Query Solr** to get data based on a **template**. Then **foreach** of that data do a **Sitecore Getitem** and **Update** a field's value.

Comment: Sounds possible. You can start with the docs here https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/indexing/find-item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first start with the following commands:

- [Find-Item](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/indexing/find-item) : Use this to query the index
- [Initialize-Item](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/indexing/initialize-item) : Use this to convert the data from the index into Sitecore items
- The items that come back can then be managed directly [like seen here](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/working-with-items#editing-items)

**Example:** The following example finds all items in the *master* index inheriting from the "Sample Item" template. Those items are retrieved and the title field is updated with the current date.

```
$criteria = @(
    @{Filter = "Equals"; Field = "_templatename"; Value = "Sample Item"; }
)
$props = @{
    Index = "sitecore_master_index"
    Criteria = $criteria
}

$items = Find-Item @props | Initialize-Item
foreach($item in $items) {
    $item.Title = "Current time: $(Get-Date)"
}
```